# how do I update an app created manually from git in Openshift?

Tags: github, openshift

If I create an app like this in my local openshift cluster (spring boot app with docker file):

```
oc new-app registry.access.redhat.com/redhat-openjdk-18/openjdk18-openshift~https://github.com/user/myrep.git --name=my-app-name
```

How can I update it later with changes that I push to the github registry? Is there something like "update-app"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a new application using the `oc new-app` command as above, you are creating a S2I (Source-to-Image) based deployment. That means that there will also be a `BuildConfig` for your application (check with `oc get bc`).

So to manually trigger a build, use the following command:

```
oc start-build my-app-name
```

`oc new-app` and `oc new-build` will also create GitHub and Generic webhook triggers automatically, so these can be used to automatically trigger a build (for example whenever there is a commit). There is more information in the documentation: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/builds/triggering-builds-build-hooks.html